# How to change the case of all characters when loading to datagridview using vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, datagridview, uppercase

I want to change the format of my `text` in `datagridview` to `uppercase` just like shown in the image

[image]

My vb.net code

```
Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspSELECTALL", cn)
    dgv1.DataSource = Nothing
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    dt.Clear()
    da.Fill(dt)
    dgv1.RowTemplate.Height = 30
    dgv1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCellsExceptHeaders
    dgv1.ColumnCount = 7
    dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgv1.Columns(0).Name = "Student ID"
    dgv1.Columns(0).DataPropertyName = "StudentID"
    dgv1.Columns(1).Name = "Last Name"
    dgv1.Columns(1).DataPropertyName = ("SurName")
    dgv1.Columns(2).Name = "First Name"
    dgv1.Columns(2).DataPropertyName = ("FirstName")
    dgv1.Columns(3).Name = "Middle Name"
    dgv1.Columns(3).DataPropertyName = "MiddleName"
    dgv1.Columns(4).Name = "Gender"
    dgv1.Columns(4).DataPropertyName = "Gender"
    dgv1.Columns(5).Name = "Birthday"
    dgv1.Columns(5).DataPropertyName = "Birthday"
    dgv1.Columns(6).Name = "Age"
    dgv1.Columns(6).DataPropertyName = "Age"

End Using
```

My store Procedure code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSELECTALL]


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  
            Birthday,getdate() AS [Today],
            Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay)
                >GETDATE() THEN 1
                ELSE 0

            END AS [age],
            StudentID,(Surname),FirstName,
            MiddleName, Gender,BirthDay,TelNum
            FROM StudentInformation
END
```

What i have tried is to put `upper` in my code just like in the code below but it does not work. Can someone help me to fix my code. Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspSELECTALL]


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT  
            Birthday,getdate() AS [Today],
            Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay)
                >GETDATE() THEN 1
                ELSE 0

            END AS [age],
            StudentID,Upper(Surname),upper(FirstName),
            upper(MiddleName), Gender,BirthDay,TelNum
            FROM StudentInformation
END
```

Comment: `but it does not work.` What does it mean? Do you get compile error, error on execution, exception? **Anyway it should be done in application layer. It is presentation only matter.**

Comment: using `upper()` in the Stored Procedure should works. When you said it does not work, are you getting any error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add Column Alias on those upper () column

```
SELECT  
            Birthday,getdate() AS [Today],
            Datediff(yy,BirthDay,getdate()) -
            CASE
                WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY,BirthDay,getdate()),BirthDay)
                >GETDATE() THEN 1
                ELSE 0

            END AS [age],
            StudentID,
            UPPER(Surname) as Surname,
            UPPER(FirstName) AS FirstName,
            UPPER(MiddleName) as MiddleName,
            Gender,BirthDay,TelNum
            FROM StudentInformation
```